Поможет ли увеличение ОЗУ на ноутбуке для ускорения производительности эмулятора Android в Visual studio?
Делаю приложения на maui для диплома, на 2 страницах в эмуляторе не подгружает повторно картинки(при первом открытии все в порядке), видимо, из-за объема информации самих данных таблиц в базе(с картинками все в порядке),база подключена через api, да и вообще часто тормозит и может долго подгружать информацию. ОЗУ на ноутбуке 16гб, стоит ли увеличить и поможет ли это для производительности эмулятора? Запускать через телефон не вариант из-за отсутствия андроида и знаний работы с этим

Очевидно, открывайте диспетчер задач и смотрите, хватает ли ОЗУ или нет

Объем памяти начинает влиять на производительность только тогда, когда память заканчивается и винда начинает свапить страницы памяти на диск.
